# Who upvoted my "late" answer so quickly?

Tags: discussion, answers, bump

I just found a question that is 3 weeks old. I don't want to link to it because I don't want anyone to think I'm trying to bring attention to my answer, so here is some info about the question:

- Question was asked over 3 weeks ago
- Question had no votes
- Question was not a "favourite" for any users
- Question had only been viewed about 25 times
- Already had one answer posted (no votes, not accepted, posted on same day as question)

Within 3 minutes of answering, I had received an upvote. This prompted me to wonder who was looking at this (almost) tumbleweed question other than me?

My initial thought was that it must be the OP, as they would be the obvious choice having been notified of my new answer. However, the OP was showing as inactive for almost 24 hours. In addition, if the OP had upvoted then it's likely I would have also warranted the answer being accepted too.

So next, I thought perhaps it popped up in one of the review queues. However, the only queue that seems applicable is the "late answers" queue, however the description for that queue says it applies to "new users", which I certainly am not.

The only other thing I could think of, is that it's pure coincidence that somebody was searching for that answer just at the time I was posting... which just seems highly unlikely.

---

So in short, I am curious, how did somebody find my answer? Is the review queue actually incorrectly described? Is there another obvious possibility I am overlooking?

Ultimately, the reason I am asking on Meta is to help grow my understandings of how SO works.

Comment: There are people lurking at the active queue.

Comment: You did, with your second account ... no point in denying that ;P. Or someone saw the bumped question on the homepage (i.e. "active" tab).

Comment: @Tom: I suppose that could be possible... When you have insomnia, you're never really asleep... and you're never really awake.

Comment: @user0042: You know what... I always forget there is other queues, I only ever use the "newest" one. It would make sense that my answer would cause it to bump... this is seeming the most likely now

Comment: anyone could have. someone maybe following one of the tags of the question and seeing active questions there..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions (10k+ rep only)

Comment: @SurajRao: Yeah I get that it could be anyone, I am not asking for a specific user... just interested to know why my answer was bought to the attention of other users

Comment: You do understand that posting an answer bumps the question onto the frontpage?

Comment: When you answer a question, it "bumps" the question, just like editing the question. That someone looked at it should not be a surprise. I don't really understand what you're asking here. Have you never seen a question on the "interesting" tab because it had a brand-new answer?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Nope. Because my "front page" is the "Newest" queue, and that certainly doesn't have bumped posts. Like I said in a comment already, I often forget that other queues exist

Comment: @CodyGray: No, I don't use the other tabs at all. I am not really asking anything specific, I am trying to expand my knowledge of SO

Comment: There are plenty of comments here that could answer my question...

Comment: Checking the overall newest feed is like trying to drink from a fire hydrant. Why not just stick to the Interesting feed?

Comment: @E_net4: Sometimes I am just really thirsty... haha. I have favourite tags to highlight questions which are applicable to my interests, and I don't really find it that difficult, I can easily spot questions I am interested in. I may have a play with the other queues though to see how it works out

Comment: @Tom The homepage and the active tab are two very different things.  The homepage orders questions based on a complex weighting formula in which how recently it was active is just one of many parameters considered.  The "active" tab purely lists question in order of activity, with no other considerations (other than removing questions with ignored tags).  An answer to a really old question is going to struggle to get to the top of people's homepages (it's not impossible, just...harder).  It will *always* go to the top of the "active" tab for the relevant tags though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you visit the site through clicking the logo or visiting https://stackoverflow.com, your frontpage consists of questions that have been recently asked or answered, or where the question or an answer to it was recently edited.

Many people <sup>[citation needed]</sup> use the site like that, so it's plausible someone saw the question bumped by your answer on their frontpage.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thanks. I never visit that page, I am always on "newest" questions. I navigate by clicking "Questions" and I also have a pinned tab in Chrome for SO, so I don't ever need to navigate to the site manually.